# Why is OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility Kicking off Builds

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

We have started making use of the [OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility](http://opshub.com/main/index.php/products/vsomigrationutility) to migrate a few projects from TFS (on-premises) to Visual Studio Online (TFVC to TFVC).

We have now migrated two projects and in both cases the migration process has kicked off literally *thousands* of builds on our VSO build agents. The projects that it kicks off the builds for seem to be random (projects that are not part of the migration). In many cases the builds are CI builds that are running against commits from weeks/months ago. When the builds are started, the majority of the builds are being started on behalf of "Anonymous".

Has anyone else experienced this with OpsHub? If so, how do we get it to stop doing this? We have four more projects to migrate and we'd love to resolve this before starting another migration because it makes our build servers unusable while we kill the (thousands of) builds.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You'd want to either disable all of your build definitions until the migration is completed, then delete any queued builds and re-enable them or have ***NO_CI*** added to the comments to prevent triggering builds. I'd recommend just disabling the build definitions during the migration.

Comment: Checkins happens at collection level so there may be some build definitions configured for every checkin for the projects(which are already there in VSO) on which the builds are triggered, could you please verify the same with your TFS administrator.

Comment: In this case, I am the administrator ;-) Since the project we are migrating is TFVC-based and the builds that are getting kicked off are all in Git-based projects, it is possible this might be a bug in VSO/OpsHub. Microsoft is looking into it. I'll follow up on this thread once I learn/hear more.

Answer (score 0):

Please check to make sure continuous builds are not enabled for the projects or source collection which is being migrated.

Comment: The strange thing is that it's kicking off builds not related to the project (i.e. running builds in other projects that are already in VSO).